# Active Record Query Datetime Overlaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm doing a simple active record query that deletes all models that overlap a certain date as follows via the following.

This is only deleting the available object that matches exactly. I.e. if the session being booked is from 1PM to 2PM, and a `trainer` has availability from 12PM - 5PM, it only deletes the time slot from 1PM - 2PM (not 1:15PM - 2:15 PM, etc.). Why isn't this working?

**UPDATE**

Below worked

```
@trainer_avails = TrainerAvailability.where(id: params[:trainer_avail_id]).where(
 'start_time <= ? AND end_time >= ?',
 DateTime.parse(params[:start_time]) + 1.hour, DateTime.parse(params[:start_time])
 )
```

Comment: I think you need to explain your data model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@trainer_avails = TrainerAvailability.where(id: params[:trainer_avail_id]).where(
   'start_time <= ? AND end_time >= ?',
    @session_detail.end_time, @session_detail.start_time
    )
```

Comment: No your intial post was better

Comment: Sorry i mean this doesnt destroy included methods

Comment: note the order of start an end. `start <= end`, `end >= start` it must work, it works for me

Comment: Is there a way to chain the destroy allI.e. @trainer_avails = `TrainerAvailability.where(id: params[:trainer_avail_id]).desotry_all(
   'start_time <= ? AND end_time >= ?',
    @session_detail.end_time, @session_detail.start_time
    )`

Comment: @DaynaJuliana, you'll never know until you try :) But I guess it should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76104/discussion-between-daynajuliana-and-ivanselivanov).

Answer (score 1):

Not following 100% what you are trying to achieve, but if you are wanting to delete all sessions between two periods, maybe try something like below.

```
TrainerAvailability.where('start_time <= ? and end_time >= ?', @session_detail.end_time, @session_detail.start_time)
```

Comment: This doesnt collect overlapping dates, only included dates

Comment: Adjusted to include overlapping dates.

Comment: This only returns an exact match, does this have to do with postgre saving dates as strings? I don't think this is comparing my paramters correctly

Comment: It seems the consensus on chat is that the above should work, EXCEPT for some reason it only returns an exact match. My assumption is that ActiveRecord is comparing `strings` not `DateTime`. Is there a way to rectify this?

Comment: Have you tried parsing the string to a datetime? there are a couple of ways - `DateTime.strptime` , `Time.parse`, `Datetime.parse` - I think `strptime` gives you a bit more flexibility to specify format. Hope that helps.

Comment: No, these all worked. It was in the id params ! WAs comparing the wrong god damn column !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [destroy_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all) method to reduce code:

```
TrainerAvailability.destroy_all('start_time <= ? and end_time >= ?', @session_detail.start_time, @session_detail.end_time)
```